# Help verify a solution showing $f\left(x \right)=\int_\Bbb{R} {{\chi _A}\left(y \right){\chi _B}\left( {x-y} \right)dy} $ is well-defined everywhere

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

The question is,

> Let $A,B⊂[0,1]$ be measurable sets with $|A|>1/2$,$|B|>1/2$ where $|*|$ denotes Lebesgue measure. Prove that
>
> a. $|A⋂(1-B)|>0$ where $1-B≔{1-x:x∈B}$ and conclude that there exist $x∈A$,$y∈B$ st. $x+y=1$.
>
> b. the function $f\left( x \right) = \int_\Bbb{R} {{\chi _A}\left( y \right){\chi _B}\left( {x - y} \right)dy} $ is well-defined, i.e. $f(x)<+∞$, for all $x∈R$.

The following is my solution. I think my solution should be correct, but I want to make sure, **especially for b)**, for which I am not very confident.

Thank you!

[image]

Comment: Your solution is correct: good job.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your solution is correct for (a). For (b), it is better like
\begin{align}
f\left( x \right) &= \int_\Bbb{R} {{\chi _A}\left( y \right){\chi _B}\left( {x - y} \right)dy} 
\\
&= \int_\mathbb{R} {{\chi _A}\left( y \right){\chi _{x-B}}\left( {y} \right)dy}
\\
&= \int_{A\cap(x-B)} {{\chi(y)}\:dy}
\\
&\leqslant m(A\cap(x-B))
\\
&<\infty
\end{align}